# Styling shared boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, qgis-custom-function, geometry-generator

I have 2 polygon layers, 1 showing roads and another showing parking restrictions on those roads (no parking, residents only, etc). I'm trying to style the layer according to the markings that would appear on the actual street (double yellow lines for no parking and white dashed line for residents only).

I've generated styles using a negative buffer in the geometry generator. But I'm not sure how to show only the section of polygon outline that are next to the curb (i.e. the shared outline of the road and restriction layers). This is as far as I have got:

[image: crossing lines]

But I'd like this as the end result (created with MS paint):

[image: desired result]

I need to achieve this without actually altering the geometry or creating any new layers that are for 'cartographic purposes only'. I found a useful question and answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138924/how-to-suppress-polygon-boundaries-shared-by-objects-of-same-type-in-qgis), but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do the polygons share a common edge (or a part of it)? I ask this with reference to the two white facing edges on the right, for example. Then, is it allowed to use a custom function?

Comment: if you want to supress the lines (like in the example you provided) you may try different "blending modes", but for what I understand, you may try to give an offset to your polygon's line (layer properties>fill>simple line>offset

Comment: @mgri Some of the restriction polygons share boundaries, whilst other do not. The key distinction is that I want to show outlines that are shared with the road outlines only. A custom function that is called from within the geometry generator would be fine.

Comment: @ElioDiaz if I offset the polygon, I will still get the entire perimeter rendered, it'll just be in a different place. Equally blending modes will effect the entire polygon, not just the part I need.

Comment: @firefly-orange please, could you share a sample dataset? I have one idea but I want to check if it is applicable to your case.

Comment: @mgri I'm unable to share the data at this point. Would you be kind enough to share your proposed solution anyway? It may be enough for me to adapt, if it doesn't 100% fit my use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I propose an approach that only recurs to a **geometry generator** and a **custom function**.

---

## Context

Let's assume to start from this situation (hopefully very close to yours), where the several parking restrictions are stored in the `"Condition"` field:

[image]

I also assume that you know how the QGIS custom functions work, otherwise this post might be helpful: [How to create custom functions in QGIS using the function editor](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2017/05/20/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-qgis-using-the-function-editor/).

---

## Preliminary task - Creating the custom function

After having loaded your layers in QGIS, open the `Field Calculator` and click on the `Function Editor` tab.

Then, click on `New file` and type `curb_lines` as the name of the new function:

[image]

You will see that a new function has been created and it is listed on the left side of the dialog. Now, click on the name of the function and replace the default `@qgsfunction` with the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def curb_lines(restrictions_layer_name, roads_layer_name, feature, parent):

    def segments(polyline):
        for x in range(0, len(polyline)-1):
            first_point = polyline[x]
            second_point = polyline[x +1]
            seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([first_point, second_point])
            idsList = index.intersects(seg.boundingBox())
            for id in idsList:
                tmp_geom = all_feats[id].geometry()
                if seg.touches(tmp_geom):
                    num.append(seg)
        return num

    layer  = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(restrictions_layer_name)[0]
    ro_layer  = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(roads_layer_name)[0]

    all_feats = {}
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in ro_layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)
        all_feats[ft.id()] = ft

    input_geometry = QgsGeometry(feature.geometry())
    line_geom = QgsGeometry(input_geometry.geometry().boundary())
    polyline = line_geom.asPolyline()
    num = []
    res = segments(polyline)

    first = True
    for h in num:
        if first:
            geom = QgsGeometry(h)
            first = False
        else:
            geom = geom.combine(h)

    return geom
```

Once you have done this, click on the `Load` button and you will be able to see the function from the `Custom` Menu of the `Expression` dialog.

---

## Solution

Firstly, go to `Layer Properties | Style` and then choose the `Rule-based` renderer.

Create two different rules (if you have only two categories, otherwise adapt it to your case): I will show you how to get a working solution only for the first category because the procedure is the same for all the others.

Double-click on the first rule and set the filter expression (*step 1*, see the image below):

```py
"Condition" = 'Residential only'
```

[image]

From the `Symbol selector` dialog, choose a `Geometry generator` as symbol layer type (*step 2*) and `Linestring / MultiLinestring` as geometry type (*step 3*).

Now, type this expression (*step 4*):

```py
curb_lines('restr', 'roads')
```

where `'restr'` and `'roads'` are the layer names for the restrictions and roads layers, respectively (adapt them to your case).

If you want to set a different style for each category, go to *step 5* and set `Color`, `Pen width`, `Offset` and so on (the answer won't cover this part).

Click on the `OK` button and repeat the previous steps for the other categories.

Finally, click on the `Apply` button for applying the changes.

You will see something like this:

[image]